# OracleConnection AutoCommit vs DbContext Transaction

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

I'm going to use the Oracle Provider for EntityFramework, and I was wondering:

According to the specs, OracleConnection will default to AutoCommit=true.

According to the EF specs, the SaveChanges method of the DbContext is transactional.

So what will happen when there is more than one action to be performed in SaveChanges? (Say - insert to two tables). Will it commit after every statement (per OracleConnection settings) or only after all the statements executed (per EF settings)?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just check it?

Comment: Yes, why not just checkit? Use a db monitoring tool. Or force some update statements that will result in a constraint violation.

EF will not commit after every statement explicitly.

Comment: I would like to check it, but currently I don't have Oracle installed, and it will take me a few days to set it up, so I thought maybe someone with experience in this field could drop a short note...